# What is the synonym for "Buckle up your seat belt"?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

What is the synonym for "Buckle up your seat belt"?

Is it ***"Take off your seat belt"***?

Comment: I haven't heard "buckle up" used this way since the early "Buckle Up for Safety" campaigns when seat belts were introduced. Nowadays I would say "Fasten/Unfasten your seat belt" since it has a lock/release mechanism.

Comment: @user3169 If want to use buckle up just simply say "Buckle up". Is that correct?

Comment: As long as you are understood, sure. But it is an idiomatic phrase related to this activity, so if someone did not hear it before they might wonder what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Take off your seat belt* has the opposite meaning. One synonym is ***put on** your seat belt*:

> [put on](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-sth-on)
>   to cover part of the body with clothes, shoes, make-up, or something similar:
>   *Put your shoes on - we're going out.*
>   *He put on his jacket.*
>   *She puts face cream on every night.*
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)